# Multiple Time Zones in Google Appengine Cron Job

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I want to schedule a task for 9:00 AM in every country. (basically 9:00 AM in every time zone). How can I schedule that in google appengine?

Will it take multiple timezones for time zone parameter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule a cron job to run every hour, because every hour there is 9 am somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite that simple because not all timezones are aligned to full hours, e.g New Delhi's timezone is GMT+5:30 .  So you need to pick all the zoneinfo that are of specific interest and manually `fold` them into as few cron entries as feasible (e.g with a local script to generate the desired cron.yaml).

Comment: Add one cron job for Delhi and, if necessary, for a few more time zones with non-hour offsets. That will give you the smallest number of cron jobs without writing a single line of code :)